# How to display InnerBlocks in render callback

Tags: block-editor

I have a block that copies the functionality of the "Columns" block. My problem is that I don't want to use the default `save` function, but use a callback function instead.
As I'm using `InnerBlocks`
my `edit` looks something like this

```
edit: ( props, setAttributes, className ) => {
.
.
.
<InnerBlocks
   template={ getColumnsTemplate( props.attributes.columns ) }
   templateLock="all"
   allowedBlocks={ ALLOWED_BLOCKS } />
```

By default, the  save function outputs the content using this as return: `<InnerBlocks.Content />`

How should the `render_callback` function in php look like in order to display the `InnerBlocks` content?

Also if `save` returns `null` then the content I put inside block doesn't get saved.

Comment: I'm not sure that server rendered blocks support nesting

Answer (score 5):

### save (JS)

> By default, the save function outputs the content using this as return: `<InnerBlocks.Content />`

This part is ok, you should still return `<InnerBlocks.Content />` in your save function:

```
save: props => <InnerBlocks.Content />
```

**Source**

> If you are using InnerBlocks in a dynamic block you will need to save the InnerBlocks in the save callback function using `<InnerBlocks.Content/>`

https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/

### render_callback (PHP)

```
function render($attributes, $content)
{
    return $content;
}
```

**Source**

> Whatever you return in save function is in $content variable of PHP render function`

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/6751#issuecomment-451550734